# I'm trying to plot graph on real time data on my website according to there patient id in select tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to plot graph on real time data on my website according to there patient_id in select tag.
In phpmyadmin database i have four column (`temp,rate,date,patient_id`)
in `followdata_temp` i getting data of temp as per time.

in main page i'm gettin select option as well as graph below it but I'm not able to plot graph on it.

// `followdata_temp.php` (from where data is fetched)

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    //query to get data from the table   
    session_start();    
    //$pid = $_POST['patient_id'];
    //echo $pid;
    $query = sprintf("SELECT time, temp FROM heart_reating where patient_id='$pid' ") or die(mysql_error()); //$pid is where patient_id is declared in page.    
    //execute query
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

my html page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChartJS - Line</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">       
    </head>
    <body>   
      <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="line-chartcanvas"></canvas>
      </div>    
      <!-- javascript -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/jquery.min.js">    
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js2/Chart.min.js">  
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">
    </script>
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {   
      /**
       * call the data.php file to fetch the result from db table.
       */
      $.ajax({
        url : "/followdata_temp.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
          console.log(data);    
          var time = [];
          var temp = [];    
          var len = data.length;    
          for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                   time.push("" + data[i].time);
            temp.push(data[i].temp);
          }  
          //get canvas
          var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");
          var chartdata = {
            labels : time,
            datasets : [
              { 
             label : "Temperature",
                data : temp,
                backgroundColor : "blue",
                borderColor : "lightblue",
                fill : false,
                lineTension : 0,
                pointRadius : 5
              }
            ]
          };   
          var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
            type : "line",
            data : chartdata
           });
    },
        error : function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });   
    });
        </script>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I wanted plot graph by selecting patient id from select that is in phpmyadmin plot graph of it as (`temp, time`)

Comment: please explain what does or does not happen. Are there errors? Does the chart not get plotted or does it look wrong etc

Comment: following errors are there.... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery-3.3.1.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
ak.html:34 
[{"time":"2019-03-27 15:03:21","temp":"100"},{"time":"2019-03-27 15:02:47","temp":"100"}]
default.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: data is fetching from database but it's not plotting on line chart.

Comment: presumably your php does send the json encoded `$result` back to the ajax function?

Comment: yes, and Data is printing as well. as ...... [{"time":"2019-03-27 15:03:21","temp":"100"},{"time":"2019-03-27 15:02:47","temp":"100"}]